# From when did the google-chrome-stable (109.0.5414.119-1) version depends on libu2f-udev?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

It looks like Google chrome has update the google-chrome-stable to 109.0.5414.119-1 which depends on libu2f-udev. However, I got this error google-chrome-stable depends on libu2f-udev; however:
Package libu2f-udev is not installed.

My question is for which new feature in chrome did they made dependent on udev? And when did they made changes?

[image]

I tried installing libu2f-udev and it worked but just curious.

Comment: How did you fix this problem? any solution?

Comment: I am having the same issue... Did you just independently install libu2f-udev?

Comment: @spdl83 I added `libu2f-udev` library in dockerfile .

Comment: @Takuhii you can install independently or add in Dockerfile.                                   
 `RUN apt update && apt install -y libdbus-1-3 libglib2.0-0 libnss3 libx11-6 libdbus-glib-1-2:amd64  \`      
    `libasound2 libgbm1 libxss1 libpango1.0-0 xdg-utils fonts-liberation libatk-bridge2.0-0 libcups2 \`
   `ffmpeg libu2f-udev \`
    `&& apt --fix-broken install -y`